# Content of div not being inserted into database

Tags: javascript, php, html, contenteditable

I have a div which uses `contenteditable` to allow the user to edit the text inside it.

When the form is submitted, I use Javascript to set a hidden input field's value as the content of the div, which is then inserted into a database.

My issue is that the div's content isn't entered into the database.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
echo'
<script>
  document.getElementById("hiddenTextarea").value =  
    document.getElementById("post").innerHTML;
  return true;
</script>
';

$post = $_POST['hiddenTextarea'];
$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO posts (post) VALUES (:post)");
$stmt->bindParam(':post', $post);
$stmt->execute();
}
?>

<form method="post">
<div id="post" contenteditable></div>
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenTextarea" name="hiddenTextarea">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Could the issue possibly that the query is executing before the Javascript code has changed the value of `#hiddenTextarea`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After various suggestions from different forums and various users, I was able to come up with a solution using Javascript's `onkeyup` event:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$post = $_POST['hiddenTextarea'];
$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO posts (post) VALUES (:post)");
$stmt->bindParam(':post', $post);
$stmt->execute();
}
?>

<form method="post">
<div id="post" contenteditable></div>
<input type="text" name="hiddenTextarea" id="hiddenTextarea">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

<script>
var contentText = document.getElementById('post');
var hiddenInput = document.getElementById('hiddenTextarea');
contentText.onkeyup = function() {
    hiddenInput.value = this.innerHTML; 
};
</script>
```

When the user types in the `contenteditable` div, it's also automatically typed into the hidden input field, which can then be defined through a variable and entered into the database.

Answer (score 0):

Use from following code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
     $post = $_POST['post'];
     $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO posts (post) VALUES (:post)");
     $stmt->bindParam(':post', $post);
     $stmt->execute();
}
?>

<form method="post">
     <textarea name="post"></textarea>
     <input type="hidden" id="hiddenTextarea" name="hiddenTextarea">
     <input type="submit" name="submit" onsubmit="return copyContent()">
</form>
```

Comment: No luck... still the same issue. Also, do you mind explaining why `name` is needed for the element?

Comment: In the js code you just put data of post to hiddenTextarea, you can use from in this case you can use from textarea tag instead of div content editable and access to that in the post directly

Comment: I had thought about that, however I later plan on allowing the user to make selected text inside the div bold or italic (using JQuery), which cannot be done with `textarea`.

Comment: why you do not use from AJAX, in this case can do this job with ajax

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112321/discussion-between-majid-abbasi-and-the-codesee).

Comment: Are you able to explain what's wrong with my current code?

Comment: let me explain why your code does not work, when you post data to PHP page all form fields will be put on $_POST or $_GET(according to your form method). in this case you changed a field after it posted and $_POST set to form fields. According to your requirement i suggest jQuery Ajax.